# Test Class to cover when empty string values are given. System.AuraHandledException: Script-thrown exception getting this error for empty string

Tags: code-coverage

Class:

```
@AuraEnabled
public Static Account getApplicationDetails(String AccountId) {
    try {
        if(String.isBlank(AccountId))
            throw new CustomException('Invalid AccountId');

        Account app = new Account (); 
        List<Account > applications = [SELECT Id, Name FROM  Account 
                                                  WHERE Name = :AccountId];
        if(!applications.isEmpty()) {
            app = applications[0];
        }
        return app;
    }
    catch(exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    } 
}


public class CustomException extends Exception {}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class NewApplicationStatus_Test {

 public static testMethod void TestOne(){
     NewApplicationStatusController.getApplicationDetails('123456');
}

     public static testMethod void TestTwo(){
      EZJoin_NewApplicationStatusController.getApplicationDetails('');
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the exception if you expect it:

```
@isTest public static void TestTwo(){
    try {
        EZJoin_NewApplicationStatusController.getApplicationDetails('');
        System.assert(false, 'Expected a thrown exception.');
    } catch(AuraHandledException e) {
      System.assert(e.getMessage().containsIgnoreCase('invalid accountid'));
    }
}
```

Note: `testMethod` is deprecated. You should use `@isTest` instead, as demonstrated here.

Comment: is it good to write try catch block in test class. some times we will not able to get what actual error is? please let me know your thought? @sfdcfox

Comment: @AnnappaPH If you are testing an exception path, you should catch the exception. Note I do not catch `Exception`, but rather `AuraHandledException` to make sure that I get exactly the error I expected. In general, if you are catching an exception in a test, you should know what the error is, otherwise you wouldn't be expecting it.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox